# How to normalize a date year i.e convert from 2 digit to 4digit Javascript

Tags: javascript

I searched this question over SO and other resources, they havent been able to help me solve the issue.
I want to by default show the date year as a 4-digit year, even the user enters a 2-digit year in an input field, basically normalizing a 2-digit year becoming a 4-digit one once the user enters the year.

html:

```
<input type="text" value="20" is="input/>
```

the output expected here is 2020 (I'm assuming all the years entered to be greater than 2000)

I used the `date.getFullYear`, but this does not accept year as a param, i.e if I do following:
Js:

```
var d = new Date("20"); //how can I pass an year to any date to get the correct date
var n = d.getFullYear();
```

the user can enter either "20" or "2020", output should be "2020".

condition: the user can enter either 2 digit or 4 digit date, if anything else, will result in error.

I'm unable to use any library or plugin at this moment for my project except for pure javascript, hence cannot use moment.

any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this condition:

```
var year = "20"
var fullYear = null;

if (year.length === 2) {
    fullYear = "20" + year;
} else {
    fullYear = year;
}
```

It checks whether the year that's supplied has two digits, if so, it prefixes the string with "20" otherwise, it keeps it the same